# Is $\hat{\theta} = 2\bar{X}$ a sufficient estimator for $\theta$? How can I prove it?

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, estimation

Given a random sample $\underline{X}_{(n)}$ of a random variable $X\sim U(0,\theta)$, is $\hat{\theta} = 2\bar{X}$ a sufficient estimator for $\theta$ ?
Given $T(\underline{X}_{(n)}) = 2\bar{X}$, I tried through $f_{\underline{X}_{(n)}\mid T=t}(\underline{x}_{(n)})$ and try to see that $\frac{f_{\underline{X}_{(n)}}(\underline{x}_{(n)})}{f_{T}(t)}$ given $T(\underline{x}_{(n)}) = t$ does not depend on $\theta$ , but I cannot find the distribution of the parameter. I tried going from $X \sim U(0,\theta)$ to $Y \sim U(0,1)$ by a linear transformation, fruitlessly.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: $2\bar X$ is not a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ (it is unbiased for $\theta$ and in fact consistent); a sufficient statistic is $\max X_i$. Are you sure about the question?

Comment: Given $T(\underline{X}_{(n)}) = 2\bar{X}$, I tried through $f_{\underline{X}_{(n)}\mid T=t}(\underline{x}_{(n)})$ and try to see that $\frac{f_{\underline{X}_{(n)}}(\underline{x}_{(n)})}{f_{T}(t)}$ given $T(\underline{x}_{(n)}) = t$ does not depend on $\theta$ , but I cannot find the distribution of the parameter. I tried going from $X \sim U(0,\theta)$ to $Y \sim U(0,1)$ by a linear transformation, fruitlessly.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. Suppose $\theta=1000$ and $\overline X=1,$ with sample size $100.$ Then the probability that at least one observation in the sample is more than $10$ is positive. But if all is as above except that $\theta=8,$ then that probability is $0.$ In other words, the conditional distribution of the data given $\overline X$ depends on $\theta.$ Thus $\overline X$ is not a sufficient statistic for this family of distributions.

Comment: Well, that was easier explained than I thought, and tried. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JesúsPiñera : Note that you can "accept" this answer. Also, probably the reason the question was closed is that its language too closely resembles that suitable for assigning homework. Lots of people have hair triggers about that.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for the insight, I'll keep that in mind for future posts.